# Installed new Git, BashRC can't find my programs now

Tags: git, bash

I've got a .bashrc with a lot of short-cut methods I've written to speed things up a little when using GIT. They've been working awesome for years, but I recently installed the newest GIT (v 2.7, I think..) and now one of my bash commands fails.

**excerpt of My .bashrc:**

```
# aliases
alias gitex=GitExtensions.exe
alias ..="cd .."

# environment variables
export PATH="$PATH:/c/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319:/c/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions:/C/Program Files (x86)/IDM Computer Solutions/UltraEdit/;"
export CDPATH=".:/c:/c/Development/ctwa:/c/Development:/c/Development/ctwaconfig"


function BashRC ()
{
  echo "_______Changing to Users/PK directory_______"
  cd /c/Users/PK/
  echo "_______Opening .BashRC_______"
  uedit32 .bashrc
}
```

So, the issue I'm running into is that when, in a git bash, I run "BashRC", I get the following error:

> $ BashRC
>
> _______Changing to Users/Paul.Kahl directory_______
>
> _______Opening .BashRC_______
>
> bash: uedit32: command not found

uedit32 is UltraEdit, which lives in the /C/Program Files (x86)/IDM Computer Solutions/UltraEdit/ directory. I can do a "Windows + R > 'uedit32'", and that opens UltraEdit, so I know it's in my path. And I haven't changed my .bashrc in years, so I don't know why this command would suddenly fail.

Comment: Are you sure the `;` on the end of your string (literal because it's inside quotes) isn't a problem? If that's parsed as part of the directory name...

Comment: ...btw, as an aside, there's no reason to explicitly `export` your `PATH` -- unless there's no initial value at all, `PATH` is always *already* marked as exported, so updates to it are copied to the environment regardless.

Comment: So your real suggestion is to remove the path export entirely. But that wouldn't explain why the `uedit32 .bashrc` fails, unless it's that `;`. I'll remove that semi colon and see what happens.

Comment: Removing that semi-colon actually worked great, except that after I type 'BashRC', and press enter, I have to them click on the git bash window and press enter again to get it to work.

Comment: That's not a problem with your shell script. Given as we provide scripting (programming) help, not end-user help here, it might be out-of-scope. That said, have you tried redirecting stdin from `/dev/null`?

Comment: ...that is: `uedit32 .bashrc </dev/null`; if it doesn't have a handle on stdin it can't block on it, unless it's dealing directly with the TTY. Which is frankly entirely plausible, which is why this is a "have you tried X?" question as opposed to a definite fix.

Comment: Never export `CDPATH`. Just set it, but don't export it. It's meant for your shell, not for processes launched from it.

Answer (score 1):

`;` is not a separator character in bash, as it is in Windows paths.

Thus, having a `;` on the end of one of your paths, it's looking for that directory name to contain a literal semicolon. Trim it off.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `uedit32 .bashrc` with `"/C/Program Files (x86)/IDM Computer Solutions/UltraEdit/uedit32" .bashrc`.

Comment: I tried the replacement, and it has the same effect as noted in the comments to the question above - it works, but only if, after typing "BashRC" and pressing Enter, I then click on the Git Bash window, and press Enter again.

Comment: That seems more like a Git Bash bug than a problem with what you're doing.